# Как изменять координаты положения объекта при каждом нажатии на кнопку?

Tags: java, swing

Не могу догадаться как в методе ActionListener при каждом нажатии на кнопку button создавать объект в том же окне, только с другими координатами (объект типа PanelPhone).

```
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {          
                    setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                    objectsPanelPhone = new ArrayList<>();
                    PanelPhone panelPhone = new PanelPhone(60, 40);
                    frame.add(panelPhone);
                    frame.revalidate();
                    frame.repaint();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Вдруг кому нужно будет:

```
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    int size = objectsPanelPhone.size();
                    PanelPhone panelPhone = new PanelPhone((60+ size*360), 40);
                    frame.setSize(600 + size*300, 600);
                    button.setLocation(230 + size*150, 500);
                    objectsPanelPhone.add(panelPhone);
                    frame.add(panelPhone);
                    frame.revalidate();
                    frame.repaint();
            }
        });
    }
```